# Cross-platform hidden settings files in node.js

Tags: node.js, path

In node.js, I'm trying to figure out a path for where my app's settings file should be, in a nice, cross-platform way.

- Unix: ~/.my-app/file
- Windows: %APPDATA%\my-app\file
- Mac: ~/Library/Application Support/my-app/file (or ~/.my-app/file)

Or something along those lines.

I don't want to hard-code looking up which OS the user is in, since that seems horribly hackish and completely non-future-proof. I was hoping there was something in `os`, `path`, or `fs`, but I've been unable to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the thing that you're looking for is the [path-extra](https://npmjs.org/package/path-extra) module that adds some utility functions to Node's built-in path. I found it [with this simple search in NPM](https://npmjs.org/search?q=settings+path), just so you know: the search engine for npm is getting quite good!

You use it this way:

```
var path = require('path-extra');
var appPath = path.datadir('appname');
var myFile = path.join(appPath, 'myFile.txt');
...
```

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing in node like what you are looking for.  You are going to have to write it yourself.

Comment: I was worried about that. Seems like a bit of an oversight.

Comment: Maybe not.  It could be argued either way.

Comment: yeah it can be difficult for a VM maintainer to decide what goes into that one convenient download and what should be left out. IMHO Node's approach to only bundle the bare-bone essentials is quite a success; i've come to like it better than Python's 'batteries included' way which does have a strong tendency to grow lots of rusty patches (they still ship a Sun Audio file read/write library ... in 2013 ...). then again, when Python was conceived, data was still carried on mules' backs over mountain passes, so it was convenient to order once, get everything.

Answer (score -1):

In answer to the question " I've been unable to find it ", .... checkout node.js 'path' module, in particular path.normalize and path.join.

I didn't find a need for other modules since 'path' solves cross-platform path construction.

```
http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_normalize_p
```

and

```
http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_path1_path2
```

Here is how I am using path.join...

```
var pth = require('path');
var fspath_myfile       = pth.join(__dirname,'fs','remote','myfile.txt');
```

which yields these file/path values if I am running out of directory 'projectdir':

```
C:\projectdir\fs\remote\myfile.txt 

/home/myusername/projectdir/fs/remote/myfile.txt
```

Comment: not sure what part of "unable to find" your answer is helpful for... the OP specifically asked for a way to get a pointer to the best location "where my app's settings file should be, in a nice, cross-platform way", and you just told him that "look ma, NodeJS `path` works on both Linux and Windows".